# Can I catch APPCRASH of command line app launched with C#'s System.Diagnostic.Process()?

Tags: c#

I need to write a C# application calling a command line tool (probably written in C), of which I know that it's unstable. I wonder if it's possible to catch random crashes of this tool in my application.

It would be enough to handle these crashes by terminating my app and writing a log message indicating that the tool has crashed.

This is how I call it (details like Process.Startinfo settings omitted):

```
Process exeProcess = new Process();
exeProcess.Start();
exeProcess.WaitForExit();
exeProcess.Close();
```

I can reproduce one particular kind of crash due to bad input data (c0000005 Access Violation Exception), so I could check for its preconditions before starting the process. But I'm sure that in production other kinds of crashes would occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a whole lot predictable about a process that crashes violently.  If it was due to an hardware exception, like AccessViolation, then there are some reasonable odds that the process exit code will be a good indicator.  Use Process.ExitCode after WaitForExit() to read it.  A value of 0 usually indicates success, although that's up to the app as well.

Comment: Good idea. That works. Thanks. Any idea, how I could prevent the crash report message from opening? Would it be wise to wait for it to open and then kill the associated WerFault.exe process?

Comment: No idea.  I think you can add that program to an exclusion list with the registry so WerFault never is used.  Ask at superuser.com

Comment: You are right, but apparently only for versions newer than XP/Server 2003: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Could try to list the processes let's say 10 times second. If your exe is closed, it crached.